# Shinydashboard tabitem freezin

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I tested a basic shinydashboard app, where input widgets placed in one tab, while result rendered in another tab. First run is fine, but after displaying result in second tab is not possible to switch back to first tab to change the input values.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)

myDF <- data.frame( let = letters, id = seq(1, length(letters)))

myHead <- dashboardHeader(
    title = "Trial"
)

mySideB <- dashboardSidebar(
    menuItem(
        "tab1", tabName = "tab1"
    ),
    menuItem(
        "tab2", tabName = "tab2"
    )
)


myBody <- dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
        tabItem(
            tabName = "tab1",
            box(
                title = "Selection",
                selectInput(
                    inputId = "sel1",
                    label = "Select a letter",
                    choices = myDF$let,
                    selected = ""
                )
            )
        ),
        tabItem(
            tabName = "tab2",
            box(
                title = "Results",
                textOutput(outputId = "res")
            )
        )
    )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    myHead,
    mySideB,
    myBody
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    filtDF <- reactive({
        myDF %>% 
            filter(let %in% input$sel1) %>% 
            select(id) %>% 
            as.character()
    })
    
    output$res <- renderText({ filtDF() })
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I read several topics, and tested the published examples but simple I don't see what's wrong with above code. Is there any advice?

#UPDATE#
OK, got the solution. I forgot to include menuItems in sidebarMenu()

```
 mySideB <- dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
       menuItem(
          "tab1", tabName = "tab1"
       ),
       menuItem(
          "tab2", tabName = "tab2"
       )
     )
 )
```